# Pings go through but application sporadically loses connectivity.

Tags: tcp, firewall, ping, ussd

**Question**
is there a possibility pings have a 100% success rate but other tcp traffic may fail randomly? If so why and how to resolve the issue?

**Background**

We are binding to a ussd gateway however we sporadically lose connectivity and are forced to rebind. Now it is my understanding that tcp conections are left open unless closed by the applicaion layer or a node between the ussd client closes the connection such as a Nat router or a Firewall render them stale and close them. The counter intuitive part is that pings between the client and ussd have 0% failure rate. 
So the question is there a possibility pings never fail but other tcp traffic may fail? If so why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  They are different protocols and are handled by different software.

IME, the usual reason for such problems is that the TCP server and/or client are buggy.

Comment: thanks for the quick response it is very unlikely that either the ussd or the client are buggy, so aside from this reason is there potential for another cause?